Can't display searchbar over image
Evening everyone, I'm a new programmer and I was having some trouble displaying a (input)searchbar over an image. Despite setting the image to background, the image is still displayed over the searchbar. Here's what I have right now(for the aforementioned topics.) All help is appreciated.
HTML
CSS
#image {
    border:0px solid;
    position:relative;
    height:200px;
    background:url('https://preview.ibb.co/fex0wK/1847p.png') no-repeat top center;
    background-size:cover;
        

}
#Searchbar {
 input {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
        top: 300px;
       
        right: -10px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
        -moz-border-radius: 0px;
         border-radius: 1px;
         border: 5px solid #2d9fd9;
         color: #a0d18c;
         width: 260px;
         height: 40px;
         padding-left: 0px;
         padding-right: 215px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 475px;

}
}
I honestly didn't know what to try, I expected it to work, and unshockingly it didnt :)

You didn't add the relevant HTML code, but a) don't use position: absolute unless you know what you're doing because it's non-responsive, i.e. doesn't work for all kinds of resolutions, and b) learn about z-index.
